# String Index Out Of Range, Vigenere Cipher

Tags: python, vigenere

I'm working on implementing a Vigenere Cipher. I'm getting the error:

> IndexError: string out of range

```
import sys

# Get the message and key 
message = (sys.argv[1]).lower()
key = (sys.argv[2]).lower()

# Open file
f = open('Cipher.txt', 'w')

for i in range(len(message)):
    if i > len(key):
        j = i % len(key)
        f.write(str(ord(message[i]) + ord(key[j]) % 26 + ord('a')))
    else:
        f.write(str(ord(message[i]) + ord(key[i]) % 26 + ord('a')))
f.close()
```

I'm getting it on the line after `f.write(str(ord(message[i]) + ord(key[i]) % 26 + ord('a')))`. I understand that my `key` may be shorter than the length of `message` that's why I put a check in front of it. For example if my key is `test` and I've gotten to the 5th character I'll come full circle back to the `t` in `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i == len(key)`, the value returned will be `i`.

Replace

```
    if i > len(key):
        j = i % len(key)
        f.write(str(ord(message[i]) + ord(key[j]) % 26 + ord('a')))
    else:
        f.write(str(ord(message[i]) + ord(key[i]) % 26 + ord('a')))
```

With:

```
a = ord('a')
  ...
    j = i % (len(key) - 1)
    f.write(str((ord(message[i])-a + ord(key[j])-a) % 26 + a))
```

Comment: That did not do anything for me.

Comment: Works but gives the wrong unicode characters, I'm sure I can just simply modify the values now. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing to watch out for is that the `%` modulo operator has the same precedence as `*` and `/`, so you may want this: `(ord(message[i]) + ord(key[j])) % 26`

Comment: @MattBrzezinski See edit. This should also fix the unicode characters